# Dynamic SQL Query from Function into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have an scalar function that returns a query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [cimpl].[GetQuery]()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN  'SELECT col1, col2, col3 from dbo.table1 '
END
```

this is an example but it something already like this and the GetQuery function can be any other function with different columns, my goal is to put this result into a temp table from inside a different sp.

With this result, I need to put it inside a temp table, my problem is that I don't want to create a temp table because I don't know which are the expected columns so I need to create it on the flight. One thing, I cannot modify the function

Comment: You could modify the returned string by replacing " FROM " with something like " INTO #MyTempTable FROM ", which, when executed, will create the temp table with the selected columns and fill it with the data from the query. I dunno if that will really help you much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM cimpl.GetQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not make it easy to work with tables that have unspecified columns.  If you knew the columns you could do:

```
create table #temp ( . . . );
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = getquery();
insert into #temp (. . . )
    exec(@sql);
```

But you don't.

I don't recommend what I'm about to suggest, but you can sort of get this to work.  I suspect that there are better ways to solve your real problem, but you haven't asked a question that describes that.

The idea is the following:

- Use `into`
- Don't use a temporary table

Assuming your query has no subqueries in the `select`, you can do:

```
select @sql = getquery();

set @sql = stuff(@sql, charindex('FROM ', @sql) - 5, 0, ' INTO _temp_table ');

exec(@sql);
```

This isn't a temporary table, so you need to remember to drop it later in the code.